# How to insert dropdown value into database using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a dropdown menu (Select) that loads a bunch of data form my table. I'm trying to insert each value into another table on clicking each selection but I have no clue on how to go about this. I've been looking around and there is nothing much I can find.

Here's my dropdown code:

```
<select id="theSelect">
    <option value="select">Select all that apply.</option>
<?php
    for($i=0; $i<count($preferences); $i++){
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $preferences[$i]['pname'];?>"><?php echo $preferences[$i]['pdesc'];?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

What I want to do is each time I select a value from the dropdown, it makes an ajax request that inserts that value into another table. Is that possible?

I would really appreciate some help with that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
    $("#theSelect").on('change', function () {
        var value = $('#theSelect option:selected').text();
        $.post("urlToActionDbSave", { valueToInsert: value }, function () {
            alert("your value have been saved to another table")
        })
    })
```

Comment: I was on this track. Actually I tried the following as a way to debug `$("#theSelect option:selected").click(function(){
        alert($("#theSelect option:selected").text());
    });` but the alert doesn't work when I click and select a value.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help